# Receiving duplicate emails with sendEmail() from sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, sendmail

I have a script running so that when a particular cell is updated in a gSheet, it sends an email so that it can be actioned. The script itself works as expected, however, when a new email is sent, it gets sent multiple times (usually 2 or 3 times), and I can't figure out how to prevent this happening. There is only 1 onEdit trigger in place, and I have EMAIL_SENT included to prevent duplicates.

See script below:

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";
function sendEmails2() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 4;  // First row of data to process
var numRows = 1000;   // Number of rows to process
// Fetch the range of cells A2:H1000
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 100)
// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i];
var emailAddress = row[5];
var message = "Message text";
var emailSent = row[6];
if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
  var subject = "Subject";
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 7).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
// Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
}
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised your not getting 1000 email sent.  Your data array has 996 rows.  If row[6] is blank it `!= EMAIL_SENT` and  an email will be sent.

Comment: There are numerous examples of this sort on code on this site.  Please take the opportunity to do some research on your own.

Comment: It works for me.  It sends just one.  How are you executing it.  Perhaps you are executing it twice.  Check you executions and look closely at their times.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this code and it sent three emails and when I ran it again it sent none:

gs:

```
function sendEmails2() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const sr = 4;
  var vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1,sh.getLastColumn() ).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < vs.length; i++) {
    var row = vs[i];
    var emailSent = row[6];
    if (emailSent != "EMAIL_SENT") { 
      MailApp.sendEmail(row[5], "Subject", "Message text");
      sh.getRange(i + 4, 7).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Sheet0 before running:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | Redacted |  |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | Redacted |  |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | Redacted |  |

Sheet0 after running:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | Redacted | EMAIL_SENT |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | Redacted | EMAIL_SENT |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | Redacted | EMAIL_SENT |

Comment: That seems to work the same as my original script - when I add data into a new row, the email still comes through twice

Comment: If you created an installable onEdit and named it onEdit then you are getting two triggers for one function.